# Loop with variable timer

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a simple metronome app with kivy but I'm having some difficulties. I have a bpm variable which i control with `+` and `-` buttons. I can change the bpm alright but the `Clock.schedule_interval` still remains in its first value.

**python**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
Window.size = 320, 568
kv = Builder.load_file("test.kv")


def job(dt):
    print("hello world")
    print(mainWindow.bpm)


class mainWindow(FloatLayout):
    tempo = 60
    bpm = 60/tempo
    labelTempo = StringProperty(str(tempo))
    event = Clock.schedule_interval(job, bpm )


    def button(self, btn):
        if btn == "+":
            mainWindow.tempo += 1
            self.labelTempo = str(self.tempo)
            mainWindow.bpm = 60/self.tempo

        if btn == "-":
            mainWindow.tempo -= 1
            self.labelTempo = str(self.tempo)
            mainWindow.bpm = 60/self.tempo


class crApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return mainWindow()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    crApp().run()
```

**Kv file**

```
<mainWindow>:

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            id: minus
            text: "-"
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.0, "top": 0.4}
            on_press: root.button("-")

        ToggleButton:
            id: start
            text: "start"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.25
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.4}

        Button:
            id: plus
            text: "+"
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.7, "top": 0.4}
            on_press: root.button("+")

        Label:
            id: tempo
            text: root.labelTempo
```

Also had lots of problems trying to update the Label text with a variable but it seems to be working OK now except when I did `print(mainWindow.labelTempo)`, I get `<StringProperty name=labelTempo>` not quite sure why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem 2 - event time interval did not change

> Clock.schedule_interval still remains in its first value.

### Solution

- Implement a new method `event_cancel_restart()` to cancel and restart event
- Invoke the new method whenever `bpm` increase or decrease

## Problem 1 - Accessing class attributes

### Solution

#### Out of scope - Access class attributes of another class

To access the class attributes declared in `class mainWindow()` outside of the class,

- Use `App.get_running_app()` to get an instance of the app
- Use `root` to get an instance of the root

#### Snippets

```
def job(dt):
    print("hello world")
    print(App.get_running_app().root.bpm)
```

#### In scope - Access class attributes within the class

To access the class attributes declared in `class mainWindow()`, you have to use `self.xyz`. Replace all occurrence of `mainWindow.xyz` with `self.xyz`

- Replace `mainWindow.tempo` with `self.tempo`
- Replace `mainWindow.bpm` with `self.bpm`

#### Snippets

```
def button(self, btn):
    if btn == "+":
        self.tempo += 1
        self.labelTempo = str(self.tempo)
        self.bpm = 60 / self.tempo
        self.event_cancel_restart()

    if btn == "-":
        self.tempo -= 1
        self.labelTempo = str(self.tempo)
        self.bpm = 60 / self.tempo
        self.event_cancel_restart()

def event_cancel_restart(self):
    self.event.cancel()
    self.event()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,

i have been using self.xyz as always but that way i can not update the static variable under the class so i though my problem would be that.

I fixed those but, 


event = Clock.schedule_interval(job, bpm)

still gives me job every one second even though i change it.

Comment: Please refer to updated post for cancelling and restarting event.

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)